# Vue filter function to return always 5 more elements

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

actually no biggie but how would a computed property filter function look like that always returns the current array + 5 more elements?

more in detail:

Template:

```
 <span class="box-content" v-for="item in activeItems" :key="item.id">
      <img class="item" :src="item.filename" />
    </span>
```

Script

```
      data: function() {
    return {
      items: [],

      limit: 1,
    };
  },
  computed: {
activeItems: function() {
    return this.items.filter( function(s) {
        if(s.length > this.limit) {
            return s;
        }
    });
//   return this.limit ? this.items : this.items;
}
},
```

on page load , an axios post request gets an object of items, whose response is pushed into the items array which is empty upon component declaration.
so axios -> get object with items -> push into empty array.
now i want to display ,like, 5 items and make a show more button.

The problem now is, my activeItems function is invalid, it does not know "this.limit" and i doubt anyway that it returns the correct result as i just made it return itself and not a set of objects / arrays.

What I would do next is trying around with splice and slice, array copies and pushing elements into it until a certain condition is met but.. is there a better way ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, `limit` is a variable with an integer value how many items should be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter function should be used to filter based on the internal values of an array. Say you have an array of objects with `persons`, and each `Person` as an `age`, then you could use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter based on that age of each entry. 
The filter function therefore goes through every entry in your array and determines whether an item should be included or excluded.

If you, on the other hand, want to limit the amount of entries based on a maximum number of entries, I would suggest you use [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), as you mentioned already.

Your computed function could be rewritten to:

```
activeItems: function() {
    return this.items.slice(0, this.limit)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in your code, `this.limit` is undefined because `this` is referencing the anonymous function. If you want to access the component, you will better use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax.
Also, `s` references an element of your array, so `s.length` will be undefined too I guess...

Now, `filter` does not seem to be the best choice for your need. I'll go with `slice` instead. Somthing like:

```js
computed: {
  activeItems() {
    return this.items.splice(0, this.limit)
  }
}
```

Where `limit` is increased by 5 when you click the show more button.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could do it. You just missed some code on it. Here how you fix it

```
activeItems: function() {
    let limit = this.limit
    return this.items.filter( function(item, s) {
        return s <= limit
    });
}
```

If you don't mind using filter, here are some way to do it.

**First** : put condition in your for loop, this one

```
<span class="box-content" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" v-if="index <= limit">
      <img class="item" :src="item.filename" />
</span>
```

**Second** is to slice your array on you desired length, this one

```
<span class="box-content" v-for="(item, index) in items.slice(0, limit)" :key="item.id">
      <img class="item" :src="item.filename" />
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with v if and v for together is, that you have a lot of <!-- --> in your code if the condition fails or so i believe. its recommended to use computed properties. Thats why i had to accept another answer, thanks for your idea though :)

Comment: Check the first solution i made, it fits your problem